# Cannot marshal field of the Structure

Tags: c#

I have a structure, of the following type in dll. But when I debugged it, I'm getting the following exception. Kindly help in fixing this.

> Cannot marshal field 'id' of type 'RCMMMResult_S': The type definition
>   of this field has layout information but has an invalid
>   managed/unmanaged type combination or is unmarshalable.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RCMMMResult_S
{

    public RCMMMResultID_s id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] value;
   // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public byte status;

    public RCMMMResult_S(bool init = true)
    {

        id = new RCMMMResultID_s();
        value = new byte[4];
        status = 0;
    }
} ;
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
[Serializable]
public struct RCMMMResultID_s
{

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1, SizeConst = 1)]
    public byte analyte_id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public byte unit_code;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public byte[] variant;
    public RCMMMResultID_s(bool init = true)
    {
        analyte_id = 0;
        unit_code = 0;
        variant = new byte[2];
    }
} ;
```

Comment: So, what is RCMMMResultID_s?

Comment: @Alex F, It was also a another Structure.

Comment: It should meet the same requirements for interoperability, as RCMMMResult_S structure.

Comment: can we *see* `RCMMMResultID_s` please?

Comment: @Marc Gravell, I have posted the other structure.

Comment: I am not sure about using SizeConst for scalar variables.

Comment: Question: are you actually using interop here? I see `Marshal` used inappropriately *more than a little*...

Comment: @Marc gravel, I need to pass the entire structute the embedded device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
public byte unit_code;
```

That is a single byte and doesn't work as a by-val array. `I1` would work fine.